# Python 2.x ; function to wait a few second for continue

Tags: python

I've just made a program, but I want to make a function in one place just to wait a few seconds to continue working. Could you tell me how does that function look?

for example

```
print 'I know'
(HERE wait few seconds to continue working)
print 'I am so layman with my trivial question'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

print 'I know'
time.sleep(1) #number of seconds to wait
print 'I am so layman with my trivial question'
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: You chose to answer a no-research question. That's your prerogative, but don't you think you should refrain from keeping derogatory references in your post then?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't see a derogatory reference? He copied OP's code and placed `time.sleep` in the slot it's supposed to go in.

Comment: @Adam, yes, I actually hesitated a little, but I've made up my mind. This answer objectively reads derogatory to the questioner, even though the code comes from the question itself. Since Joren has decided to answer the question, I believe replacing that text would have been more courteous (even with something like "Now you know" and "It did not take long" ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Fair enough. Frankly I think the failure here is choosing to answer the question instead of (presumably instead of, at least) closing it. I don't mind the carbon copy of the asker's code, even if it was originally self-flagellating.